# How to stop next button from showing the first div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code which will navigate between each `div` on button click.
If I have 5 `divs` and I click `next` button 5 times it reaches end. But when I click 6th time, it is showing 1 st `div` again like a loop. Same is the case with `previous` button. How to stop going from 5 to 1? And if I want to go back to `div 1` from,the only way should be to click `previous` button and go.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsJbu/)

html :

```
<div class="divs">
    <div class="cls1">1</div>
    <div class="cls2">2</div>
    <div class="cls3">3</div>
    <div class="cls4">4</div>
    <div class="cls5">5</div>
    <div class="cls6">6</div>
    <div class="cls7">7</div>
</div>
<a id="next">next</a>
<a id="prev">prev</a>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".divs div").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });

    $("#next").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
        else {
            $(".divs div:visible").hide();
            $(".divs div:first").show();
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("#prev").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
        else {
            $(".divs div:visible").hide();
            $(".divs div:last").show();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: The jsfiddle is nice, but can you move your code to the question and keep the jsfiddle for reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `else` block from each click callback. When no more `div`s are visible the `else` block will hide all visible `div`s and show the first when clicking next, or the last when clicking previous.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".divs div").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });

    $("#next").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
        return false;
    });

    $("#prev").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

just update the next and prev click function so it wont return back to the first and last div

```
 $("#next").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").next().show().prev().hide(); 
        return false;
    });

    $("#prev").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
        return false;
    });
```